# How do I obtain the entire code of a website to scrape all images (python)

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to create a web scraper using Python to create my own dataset of pictures of dogs and pictures of cats. I want to scrape a certain amount of pictures from the following site: https://unsplash.com/images/animals/dog.

The problem I encounter is that the Page source does not show all the pictures as opposed to the code from Inspect element (that contains all HTML, CSS, and JavaScript). How can I obtain the full code to be able to scrape all images? I tried using Selenium and Dryscrape, but to no success...

Here is my code:

```
#Import
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import random
from google.colab import drive

#Directory
drive.mount('/content/drive')
data_dir = 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Web scraper/Images/Dogs'

#Image scraper
url = "https://unsplash.com/images/animals/dog"
source_code = requests.get(url)   #Gets source code from website
plain_text = source_code.text     #only gets text from source code
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)  #Parses through the HTML of site

for div in (soup.find_all('div', class_= "_3oSvn IEpfq")):
  img = div.find_all('img')                           #Finds all img in divs

  for link in img:                                    #Traverses all img
    src = link.get("src")                             #Gets contents of src from img
    img_name = random.randrange(1,500)                #creates a unique name
    full_name = data_dir + str(img_name) + ".jpg"     #adds file type name
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, full_name)        #Fetch image of url and save into dir
```

Comment: Use Selenium WebDriver to execute the JavaScript that loads elements dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar I tried doing that before but I couldn't figure out how to incorporate it into my code... Any suggestions?

Comment: @Barmar I think even with selenium you would run into some issues, because the images are dynamically loaded when the user scrolls

Comment: There's no automatic way to see what's loaded dynamically other than emulating the user actions that cause them.

Comment: There's no way to know what images *might* be loaded. It's equivalent to the halting problem.

Comment: Exactly for those reasons I would recommend not using Selenium, I will post an answer using http requests to solve this

Comment: Thank you @JohnKrakov, that will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late response, I was a bit busy.

What I recommend is that you use their API endpoint, which is meant for developers rather than actual users. The python code below does exactly that. I have commented it extensively, but if you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

```
import requests, json

def fetchImages(base_url, maximum, res):
  #create an empty list that will contain the urls
  url_list = []
  #amounts of photos per page, it seemed to be capped at 30
  chunk_size = 30
  #fetch images on a given page index using requests
  def fetchChunk(idx):
    #response
    url = '%s?page=%d&per_page=%d' % (base_url, idx, chunk_size)
    #response text
    return requests.get(url).text
  #parse the received chunk from a string to a dictionnary
  def parseChunk(chunk):
    #the json library does the actual parsing
    data = json.loads(chunk)
    #'photos' is the sub-dictionnary containing the images
    images = data['photos']
    #loop through each photo from the page and keep only the url
    for img in images:
      #returns 5 urls, one for each resolution
      img_url = img['urls'][res]
      #add the url to the list
      url_list.append(img_url)
  #the current page index 
  #although negative indices are valid with that api, I will stick to positive ones by convention
  idx = 0
  #continue fetching pages until there's as many or more images than the max amount
  while len(url_list) < maximum:
    #fetch the chunk
    chunk = fetchChunk(idx)
    #parse it
    parseChunk(chunk)
    #increase the index
    idx += 1
  #trim the list so it contains the maximum amount
  url_list = url_list[:maximum]
  return url_list

#you can set that to 'cat' in order to fetch pictures of cat instead
animal = 'dog'

#api endpoint for image list
base = 'https://unsplash.com/napi/landing_pages/images/animals/'
url = base + animal

#resolution can be 'full', 'raw', 'regular', 'small' or 'thumb'
resolution = 'regular'

#the number of images to fetch, the website has a seemingly endless amount of dog pictures, but I would recommend not setting that number to high
#from what I've seen, fetching 2500 takes about 20 seconds, so if you plan on fetching a whole lot of photos, I would recommend using a specialized API for that
maximum = 60

#prints array of urls
print(fetchImages(url, maximum, resolution))
```

Anyways, I wish you good luck with the rest of your project!

Here's a repl.it link if you wish to use the code directly, without the extensive commenting: https://repl.it/repls/ClosedWarmheartedTheory

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It works perfectly as intended and its easy to understand too! I just have one question regarding the fetchChunk method, and that is, where did you get the url from?

Comment: @alphaverse159 You can read more about the api over here : https://unsplash.com/developers. But if there had been no dedicated API, you could have inspected the network requests with your browser developer tools and try to mimic the relevant ones.

Answer (score 0):

if you still need it, try this one:
https://pypi.org/project/unsplash-get/
example of code:

```
from unsplash_get import search, save_img

# get list of urls
word = 'orange'
urls = search(word)

# store images if needed
for key, url in enumerate(urls[:10]):
    file = '{}_{:03}.jpg'.format(word, key)
    save_img(url, file)
```